# How to convert SQL import to Django import?

Tags: python, sql, django, database

I'm trying to import data from a database using Django.  This was previously done using SQL, but now I'm trying to use Django instead of SQL.  I'm not familiar with SQL really and am having trouble converting the SQL import to a Django one.

So far, I've converted `con = psycopg2.connect("dbname='mydatabase' user='mydatabase_reader' host='xxx.xxx.xx.xx' password='test'")` to `users = EventTransactions.objects.using('mydatabase').filter('profitcenter_id'=profitcenter_id, 'actualdatetime'=date).values('')` but that's as far as I've gotten.  Right now, I'm working on using the for loop to grab information for each day.

```
def handle(self, *args, **options):

        r = redis.Redis(host=REDIS_HOST, db=REDIS_DB)

        memberships = MEM_MAP_INV.keys()

        start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(options['start_date'],'%Y-%m-%d').date()
        end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(options['end_date'],'%Y-%m-%d').date()

        profitcenter_id = options['profitcenter_id']

        # number of days passed
        elapsed_days = (end_date - start_date).days

        dates = [start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in range(elapsed_days)]

        con = psycopg2.connect("dbname='mydatabase' user='mydatabase_reader' host='xxx.xxx.xx.xx' password='test'")
        cur = con.cursor()

        for date in dates:
             counts = {}
             for m in memberships:
                membership = tuple(MEM_MAP_INV[m])

                 sql = cur.mogrify("""SELECT count(*) from eventtransactions WHERE profitcenter_id = %s AND date(actualdatetime) = %s""",
                                   (profitcenter_id, date))

                 # have to split into two cases due to how postgres queries for NULL values
                 if m == 'n/a':
                     sql = cur.mogrify(sql + """ AND membertype IS NULL""")
                 else:
                     sql = cur.mogrify(sql + """ AND membertype IN %s""",(membership,))

                 cur.execute(sql)
                 count = cur.fetchone()[0]

                 counts[m] = count

            # prepare for redis
            r_key = 'urec:counts:%s:%s' % (profitcenter_id, str(date))
            counts = json.dumps(counts)
            r.set(r_key,counts)

         cur.close()
         con.close()
```

Here is what is in the EventTransactions model:

```
    eventtransactions_id = models.IntegerField()
    profitcenter_id = models.IntegerField()
    customer_gender = models.TextField()
    customer_firstname = models.TextField()
    customer_lastname = models.TextField()
    actualdatetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    custnum = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    birthdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    membertype = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    eventname = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: It would be easier if you would provide the database structure and information what exactly you would like to achieve

Comment: I included the model for the database structure in my question

Comment: Great but now please also add what exactly would you like to achieve as converting SQL to Django is rather a path and not the task objective itself.

Comment: Django as an ORM allows to extract data in different ways so understanding your goal makes it much easier to select a proper method for that.

Comment: I would like to create a loop that will count the number of event transactions for each membership type per day and store it in a dictionary where the key is the membertype and the value is the number of event transactions for that membertype on that day

Comment: When you say per day I assume you would like to pass some date range and calculate it for every day in that range correct?

Comment: Yes, the terminal is used to load the data in development and the programmer specifies the date range

Comment: What version of django are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.11.2

Answer (score 0):

So you can achieve your goal like this:

```
        from django.db.models import Count
        from django.db.models.functions import TruncDay

        start_date = datetime.date(2019, 7, 20) # We enter start date
        end_date = datetime.date(2019, 7, 26) # We enter end date
        values = list(TestModel.objects.annotate(day=TruncDay('actualdatetime')).values('day','membertype').annotate(count=Count('id')).filter(actualdatetime__gte=start_date).filter(actualdatetime__lte=end_date))
```

Sample output:

```
[
  {
    'membertype':'A',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    20,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'A',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    25,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'B',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    20,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'B',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    21,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'B',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    22,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'B',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    24,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'C',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    24,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'D',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    20,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'D',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    24,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'D',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    25,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'E',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    26,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'F',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    23,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'G',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    21,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'G',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    24,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'G',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    25,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'H',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    21,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'H',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    23,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'H',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    26,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'I',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    25,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'K',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    20,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'K',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    23,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'K',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    25,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':2
  },
  {
    'membertype':'K',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    26,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'L',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    21,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'L',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    22,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'M',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    23,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'O',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    21,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'O',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    23,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'P',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    20,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':2
  },
  {
    'membertype':'Q',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    21,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'Q',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    25,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'R',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    26,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'S',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    25,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':2
  },
  {
    'membertype':'T',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    24,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'U',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    23,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'V',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    20,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'W',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    20,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'W',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    22,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':2
  },
  {
    'membertype':'W',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    23,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'X',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    20,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'Y',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    26,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'a',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    25,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'c',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    20,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'c',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    21,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':2
  },
  {
    'membertype':'c',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    22,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':2
  },
  {
    'membertype':'c',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    25,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':2
  },
  {
    'membertype':'c',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    26,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'e',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    20,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'e',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    21,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'f',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    24,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'f',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    26,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':3
  },
  {
    'membertype':'g',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    21,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'g',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    22,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'h',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    26,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'i',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    20,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'j',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    24,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'j',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    26,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'l',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    21,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':2
  },
  {
    'membertype':'m',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    21,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'m',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    24,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':2
  },
  {
    'membertype':'m',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    25,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'m',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    26,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'n',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    21,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'n',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    26,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'o',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    20,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'o',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    21,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'o',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    23,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'o',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    25,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'q',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    21,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'r',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    22,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':2
  },
  {
    'membertype':'r',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    25,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'s',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    21,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'s',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    23,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'s',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    24,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'t',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    20,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'t',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    26,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'u',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    24,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'v',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    25,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'v',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    26,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'w',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    21,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'w',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    24,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'w',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    26,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'x',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    23,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'y',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    24,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'y',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    25,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'z',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    21,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':1
  },
  {
    'membertype':'z',
    'day':datetime.datetime(2019,
    7,
    23,
    0,
    0,
    tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'count':2
  }
]
```

This fragment `TestModel.objects.annotate(day=TruncDay('actualdatetime'))` annotates our model with a day as you used DateTimeField in your model so we need to truncate the time and leave only date.

Next `.values('day','membertype')` this fragment goups by newly added column `day` and `membertype`

`.annotate(count=Count('id'))` This is counting instances in our groups

And last but not least we filter the result by date:
`.filter(actualdatetime__gte=start_date).filter(actualdatetime__lte=end_date))`

Also note that in your model you allow many fields to be null so not all results will be grabbed by this query. And as a side note I would change

`membertype = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)`

To:

`membertype = models.CharField(max_length=10)`

As `TextField` is for storing really long string which I guess `membertype` is not. Also I guess it shouldn't be null

Answer (score 0):

I believe mrangry777's answer includes a lot of unnecessary details. You said you want a count of event transactions per member type for a given day. All you have to do is filter the queryset down to what you are looking for, and then get the count of the query set. There is no need to truncate the time; if your model has datetime fields, then you can provide it datetime.datetime objects for the filter rather than making an unnecessary truncation. For example:

```
#Midnight on July 25th
start_date = datetime(2019, 7, 25, 0, 0, 0)
#Midnight on July 26th
end_date = datetime(2019, 7, 26, 0, 0, 0)

count_totals = {}
for member in membertype:
    daily_event_transactions = MyModel.objects.filter(actualdatetime__gte=start_date).filter(actualdatetime__lt=end_date).filter(membertype=member)
    count_totals[member] = daily_event_transactions.count()
```

Another benefit of this solution is that the use of `count()` does not evaluate the queryset, whereas the use of `list()` does. This means the code will run faster.

Comment: I strongly disagree with your solution. First off you do not present how do you get distinct member types. Secondly your solution gives a count of transactions in a given range and not the count for a specific day. Where as my gives transaction count for each day in a given range. And last but not least it generates way more queries. Given 10 day range and 10 member types your solution will need 100 queries where is my do it in 1. Also you will need a way to supply each date range in a loop outside this script and then merge the results into a single report.

Comment: I answered the question they asked, which was to use loops (I chose the loops they have inside the code they provided, which already get member type, therefore I do not have to provide those for them) to solve the problem. They asked for a loop, my solution uses a loop. Clearly since the way it was being done with the raw SQL, 100 queries didn't bother them before. I'm sorry me answering the question the way they asked causes you to disagree with my solution, but they didn't ask for a "better way" to do what they were doing. Maybe they need it to be a loop for something else, we don't know.